# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomePage: ([object Object], ?)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-forms

well I'm collecting data from the template using forms but it gives Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomePage: ([object Object], ?).
I'm not sure where I'm lagging.

Mostly the chances of the wrong code will be in the template but I can't figure it out.

here is my template:

```
<ion-content padding>
 <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="saveNote(formGroup.value)">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" formControlName="date"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item> 

  <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Title</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" name="title" formControlName="title" required></ion-input>
     <div class="alert" *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['title'].valid  &&
      formGroup.controls['title'].touched ">{{titleAlert}}</div>
   </ion-item>
   
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Content</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="content" formControlName="content" required></ion-input>
    <div class="alert" *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['content'].valid  &&
      formGroup.controls['content'].touched ">{{contentAlert}}</div>
   </ion-item>

  <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid" outline>Save Note</button>
 </form>
</ion-content>
```

and the typescript file:

```
import { Note } from './../../model/node.model';
import { TodoService } from './../../providers/todo-service/todo-service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import {  FormControl,Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-note',
  templateUrl: 'add-note.html',
})
export class AddNotePage {

  formGroup:FormGroup;
  note:Note;
  date:Date = new Date();
  title:string ='';
  content: string ='';
  titleAlert:string = 'Add a valide title!';
  contentAlert:string = 'not a valide content!';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){
        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
          title:new FormControl(),
          content: new FormControl(),
          date:new FormControl()
        });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AddNotePage');
  }

  saveNote(note:Note){
    console.log(note);

  }

}
```

Note model that I am using

```
export interface Note{
    title:string,
    content:string,
    date:Date,
    createDate:number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code section you share with us...

The error is in the HomePage component.

Comment: would you please be a little bit specific. I mean what would be the error in the HomePage?

Comment: From the title of your error I can know that the error is in:
**Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomePage** ...

But I can't know what the error is because you are not sharing the HomePage code.